# SSL Certificate verify failed in Telegram Webhook

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, webhooks, telegram-bot

I am Trying to set up a Webhook for my Telegram Bot and I'm facing an issue with Telegram SSL certification:

`{"ok":true,"result":"url":"https://example.com:443/index.php","has_custom_certificate":true,"pending_update_count":2,"last_error_date":1503222412,"last_error_message":"SSL error {337047686, error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed}","max_connections":40}}`

I bought this SSL certificate from COMODO which is supported by Telegram and I tired all possible ports, and uploaded the `.pem` using this command:

`curl -F "url=https://example.com:443/harfbeme/index.php" -F "certificate=@/etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem" https://api.telegram.org/botTokenID/setWebhook`

I also tried the Telegram method described [here](https://core.telegram.org/bots/self-signed), but I got the same error.
I checked [this page](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks) too and my server met every requirements.

Any idea why I get `certificate verify failed` error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [telegram bot SSL error: SSL error {error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls\_process\_server\_certificate:certificate verify failed}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49308744/telegram-bot-ssl-error-ssl-error-error1416f086ssl-routinestls-process-serve)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure after buying SSL , Setting it on Your Domain?
The SSL Domain , Webhook Domain is must same and SSL certificate is Must set on Domain in Settings.